# Laravel: Accessors with Pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I have tips in a polymorphic relationship with Shops, Restaurants and Trips (for tour packages).

I am trying to fetch all reviews a user has given, and for what.

I’ve added an accessor:

```
public function getHeadlineAttribute($value)
{
  $class = get_class($this->tippable);

  switch ($class){
      case 'App\Shop':
      case 'App\Restaurant':

          return $this->tippable->brand->name;
      case 'App\Trip':
          return $this->tippable->from.' to '.$this->tippable->to;
      default:
          return '';

  }
}
```

And would like to fetch something like:
`$user->tips()->with('headline')->paginate(5);`

I see I can’t use “with” for accessors. Any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `$appends` parameter to your Tip class. You don't need to do anything else.

```
class Tip extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['headline'];
}
```

Comment: Yep. You've been faster than me :D